# Is Apostasy considered a punishable offence in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, vedas, smriti, atheism, non-hindu

If someone decides to Leave Hinduism and become atheist, do any the scriptures (Vedas, Smritis, Puranas) consider it an offense worthy of punishment and prescribe any punishment for it? Just like how scriptures list punishments for offences like stealing, brahmahatyā etc?

If yes, what punishment do the scriptures prescribe? Please answer with reference.

Comment: Apostacy means someone who has left a belief system. How can he be affected by something he doesn't believe?

Comment: Related question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15756/what-does-the-hindu-religion-think-of-apostasy

Comment: @User29449 You didn't understand the question. What I am asking is whether any Hinduism texts consider Apostasy an offense worthy of punishment or not and if they do , do they mention any punishment for it ? just like how a set  punishment is listed in scriptures like manusmriti for offences like stealing, murder etc.

Comment: @Exnihilio Yes they do. If it means to demean or criticize Vedas without understanding its true sense. But they aren't followed generally.

Comment: @User29449 You may write an answer if you have the necessary scriptural references. Thanks

Comment: Apostasy doesn't make sense in the Indic framework, it makes more sense in the Abrahamic framework. But what if a Hindu accepts and starts following a non-Hindu mata, and gives up on core Hindu principles such as acceptance of Veda. Is such a person committing an aparādha deserving of daṇḍa, as per smṛtis? This person is committing a pāpa, but not an aparādha. So, s/he wouldn't receive any daṇḍa from Rājā, unless s/he deliberately does some aparādha. For e.g. if a Hindu turned Muzlim insults temples, s/he commits an aparādha deserving of daṇḍa, even though s/he isn't Hindu anymore.

Comment: There have been Bauddhas, Jainas, etc., but there weren't daṇḍita by Rājā because of following their mata (because there is no such provision in smṛtis and because that doesn't make sense in Indic framework), many (including Buddha) came from what we can call today 'Hindu' families. However, only if these people commit aparādhas as a result of their matīya vicāra (such as desecrating a temple), only then they're to be daṇḍita as per śāstras, not otherwise.

Comment: They also fall within the sway of Rājadaṇḍa, if they commit aparādhas such as murder, theft, assault, etc., just like any other citizen of rājya.