Namaskar, is atheism or agnostism or being irreligious or charvaka or being a skeptic a sin in Hinduism?
Please give me scriptural support, Sruti is highly recommended, because I don't want to know your opinion, I want to know what God or the Rsis say about it.
Just assume that they don't believe in god,atma or  brahman, they reject both Saguna and nirguna brahman, reincarnation, afterlife, karma law, any  form of ritual, any form of rule except the secular constitution, they won't believe what their senses can not sense.
Of course they may watch porn,do sex before marriage,etc which are sins but my question is not about the effects of the belief/disbelief, my question is about the belief/disbelief itself, on whether the belief/disbelief itself is a sin or not
Thank you


It is a modern trend to claim that those who do & believe the abovementionedare as legitimate Hindus as does who don't do these, but such an opinion is unjustifiable scripturally.

My question is not whether they are Hindu or not,but whether it's a sin to hold such belief/disbelief according to Hinduism

Yes, it is a sin and leads to rebirth. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16484/34973

There are 2 types of atheist, one knows god doesn't exist and therefore doesn't believe in god, the other doesn't know god exists or not therefore they don't believe in god, one doesn't believe in god due to conviction,the other is due to doubt, so are both beliefs or disbeliefs a sin ?
